# How edit the last even page of a chapter?

Tags: graphics, page-breaking

Is it possible to edit the last even page of a chapter?

Problem:
**I would like to insert a single background image (on all even pages).**

> > This page (even page) is automatically included at the end of the chapter, when it ends in an odd page, *\documentclass[twoside]{book}*

See the example at the end of chapters:

[image]

Code MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{emptypage}
    
\title{MWE TWO-SIDED DOCUMENT EDIT}

\author{Marcio Lord}

\date{Jul 2020}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{Background Image}
\rhead{Page ~~}
\lhead{\thepage ~~ Test}
\rfoot{Teste ~~\thepage}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{See page 6}

\lipsum[1-9]


\chapter{See Next Page}

\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{Done!}

The end.

\end{document}
```

Doc Link: https://www.overleaf.com/read/ybvmvhvsjgqm

I've tried everything. I'm about to go crazy!

**Input a wallpaper on even page, is it possible to edit?**

Comment: PS. In the Table of Contents (or Summary), I already used a background image in \usepackage{background}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slightly change `\cleardoublepage` and use the `background` package.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{%
  \clearpage
  \if@twoside
    \ifodd\c@page
    \else
      \hbox{}%
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \backgroundsetup{
        contents=\includegraphics{example-image},
        angle=0,
        scale=1,
      }\BgThispage
      \newpage
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{See page 6}

\lipsum[1-9]


\chapter{See Next Page}

\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{Done!}

The end.

\end{document}
```

[image]

With some tricks we can also add a database for different images to add:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\emptypagebackground}{}
 {
  \marciolord_bg:
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\backgroundimages}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \__marciolord_bg_add:n
 }

\seq_new:N \g_marciolord_bg_options_seq
\seq_new:N \g_marciolord_bg_images_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__marciolord_bg_add:n
 {
  \__marciolord_bg_add:nn #1
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__marciolord_bg_add:nn
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_marciolord_bg_options_seq { #1 }
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_marciolord_bg_images_seq { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \marciolord_bg:
 {
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \g_marciolord_bg_images_seq = 0 }
   {
    \backgroundsetup
     {
      contents=\begin{tabular}{c}NO~IMAGE \\ AVAILABLE\end{tabular},
      angle=45,
      scale=8,
     }
   }
   {
    \seq_gpop_left:NN \g_marciolord_bg_options_seq \l__marciolord_bg_option_tl
    \seq_gpop_left:NN \g_marciolord_bg_images_seq \l__marciolor_bg_image_tl
    \backgroundsetup
     {
      contents=\__marciolord_bg_use:VV \l__marciolord_bg_option_tl \l__marciolor_bg_image_tl,
      angle=0,
      scale=1,
      color=red,
     }
   }
  \BgThispage
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__marciolord_bg_use:nn
 {
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__marciolord_bg_use:nn { VV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{%
  \clearpage
  \if@twoside
    \ifodd\c@page
    \else
      \hbox{}%
      \emptypagebackground
      \newpage
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\backgroundimages{
 {width=\paperwidth}{example-image-a},
 {}{example-image-b},
 {angle=90,height=\textheight}{example-image},
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{See page 6}

\lipsum[1-9]

\chapter{See Next Page}

\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{Done!}

The end.

\chapter{Another one}

The end.

\chapter{Missing!}

The end.

\end{document}
```

If the database has been used up, you'll get “No image available” and you'll know that you need to add another image.

[image]

Comment: An error occurred: the image appeared on all pages = (

Comment: In the Summary, I already used a background image, and when I did what I said, I lost this image.

How could I solve it?

Comment: @MarcioLord Sorry, it works for me. Wh9ch of the two solutions did you try?

Answer (score 0):

@egreg
**\usepackage[pages=some]{background**} this definition made it possible to use only one background image.
What you have implemented has removed 1 background image you were using in the table of contents.

- When I leave `\usepackage{background}` it alone, it shows the same background image on every page.

How to use several different backgrounds in same document?

Comment: I solved it using other methods of inserting image in the background
With tikz, for example

Comment: Thank you so much @egreg