# In the book class, add a full-page image in the even page preceding a new chapter

Tags: graphics, floats, books

I'm making a template for a friend who's been writing a fiction book for years, struggling with his time commitment (family happens). My goal is to completely separate format from content (hence `LaTeX`), so he can focus on his story.

I wanted to add an image before a chapter. In the book class, new chapters start on *odd* pages. Would it be possible to add a full page image in the immediately preceding *even* page?

MWE

```
\documentclass[a5paper,demo]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{Captain Awesome in the Awesome land}
\author{Eric Cartman}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \frontmatter
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
    \chapter{Awesome}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    
    \begin{figure}[p]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{dummy.pdf}
    \end{figure}
    
    \chapter{More Awesome}
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

This adds a black square dummy placeholder image at the end of chapter 1, plus a white page so chapter 2 starts on the *odd* side of the book. I would like this placeholder image immediately before chapter 2.

BTW, in the template I'm putting the chapters on separate `.tex` files, and adding them into the book via a pattern expansion loop. That way my friend wouldn't even need to type `\include{chap37}` in the master document.

Thanks

EDIT: To clarify, the request is the page of placement for that image. I don't care if it's considered part of Chapter 1 or 2. I believe it needs to be part of Chapter 1, because Chapter 2 must begin in the heading, for TOC purposes. But in a book with 37 chapters, I might want to add some images in the preceding even page to some of those chapters, not to all of them. And it will definitely be a different image in each case. Something related to the story of that chapter. And some chapters will end in an odd page. Some will end on an even page.

EDIT 2: I found a partial solution. The chapter in question should have this instead of simply `\chapter{}`

```
\cleartoevenpage
\includegraphics{chapter pic}
\chapter{chapter title}
```

This is the behavior I wanted, needed. However, I'm also using `\part`. The clear page after the part page plus the clear page before the image puts two white pages after the part sheet, which is undesirable. In this case, the image should be placed on the page after the `\part` and before `\chapter`. The modified MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,demo]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{Captain Awesome in the Awesome land}
\author{Eric Cartman}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \frontmatter
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
    \part{Foo}
    \chapter{Awesome}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \part{Bar}
    \cleartoevenpage
    \begin{figure}[p]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{dummy.pdf}
    \end{figure}
    
    \chapter{More Awesome}
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW, so far I tried the ``float`` package with option H, and the ``placeins`` package, putting ``\FloatBarrier`` in several places, without success.

Comment: An if the precending even page has text on it?

Comment: Somewhat related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552180/how-edit-the-last-even-page-of-a-chapter

Comment: If the preceding page (an even page) has text in it, then an empty page must be added (odd side), then the image in an even page, then new chapter on the odd page. The ``book`` class usually takes care of this

Comment: Are you sure that the `book` class is best for that? Existing alternatives are the standard `memoir` and the custom `novel`. I have another custom class (not public yet) that addresses the very question you asked, for exactly that reason. It does it by not automatically clearing to recto (upon request). Also depends whether the finished product is an Ebook or paper book. Presumably paper, or the question makes less sense.

Comment: Thanks @rallg. You are right. I switched to ``memoir`` because it provides more options for configuration. I manage to do what I wanted with ``\cleartoevenpage``. However, when using ``\part``, the ``\cleardoublepage`` after part is followed by the ``\cleartoevenpage``, leaving two blank pages consecutively. I will need to add a few if clauses to work this one out

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust the `\cleardoublepage` definition. Replace the original empty `\hbox{}` on the even page with `\noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}`.

> The original code of `\cleardoublepage`:

```
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside\ifodd\c@page\else\hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
```

> The adjusted version of `\cleardoublepage`:

```
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside\ifodd\c@page\else\noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
```

> A full example (note: before `contents` there will be also a full page image, because `contents` is unnumbered `chapter` as well):

> Edits: add a toggle in the code `\ifaddimages`, set it to true when want the image to be added or false when don't want to add. Define a new command `\theaddimage` expanded to the image name which will be added. Redefine this command to change the added images.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{Captain Awesome in the Awesome land}
\author{Eric Cartman}
\newif\ifaddimages\addimagestrue
\newcommand{\theaddimage}{example-image-a}
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside\ifodd\c@page\else\ifaddimages\vspace*{-\topskip}\vspace*{\fill}\noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{\theaddimage}\vspace{\fill}\else\hbox{}\fi\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \frontmatter
    \tableofcontents
    \renewcommand{\theaddimage}{example-image-b}\addimagesfalse
    \mainmatter
    \chapter{Awesome}
    \addimagestrue
    \lipsum[1]
    \chapter{More Awesome}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \chapter{More Awesome}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did not explain myself sufficiently. I wanted to add a single image in the even page before a specific chapter. I could want to add only one, or a different image  before every chapter, or only before some of them. So your approach, although interesting and illuminating, does not satisfy my current needs

Comment: @phollox You could put some `if` statements in the code. Let me work on some examples.

Comment: Your answer gave me the idea of changing the definition of ``\chapter```, to add the image in the preceding page. Something like a chapter with two arguments: the title and the path to the image

Comment: @Yes, you can do that as well. See my edits in the answer.